# SQL: count accounts with certain transaction ID present in each of past 3 months

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a SQL script that counts # of accts with certain transaction IDs in a given month.  I want to modify this so that it only counts # of accts if it placed those types of transactions in each of the past 3 months, not just in any given month.  This is to filter out one-time events.

I'm fairly new to SQL and have not been able to find a clear answer through searches I made.  Would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

```
SELECT
   CLDR.YEAR_MONTH
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT TRAN.ACCT_NBR) AS IC_DD --counts all unique Acct numbers

FROM
   REPORTS.FINANCIAL_TRAN AS TRAN

INNER JOIN REPORTS.ACCT AS ACCT ON TRAN.ACCT_NBR=ACCT.ACCT_NBR
INNER JOIN REPORTS.DATE AS CLDR ON TRAN.TRAN_DT=CLDR.CALENDAR_DATE

WHERE
   TRAN.TRAN_CD IN ('id1','id2','id3')  --Filters on Transaction IDs
 AND
   TRAN.TRAN_DT BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'

GROUP BY
   CLDR.YEAR_MONTH

ORDER BY
   CLDR.YEAR_MONTH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to join to both the `ACCT` and the calendar table:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM
 (
   SELECT ACCT_NBR
   FROM REPORTS.FINANCIAL_TRAN AS TRAN
   WHERE
      TRAN.TRAN_CD IN ('id1','id2','id3')  --Filters on Transaction IDs
    AND
      TRAN.TRAN_DT BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'
   GROUP BY ACCT_NBR
   -- rows for all three months exist for this account 
   HAVING Count(DISTINCT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tran_dt)) = 3
 ) AS dt
```

Edit:

Based on comments this should not be done for a fixed range of months, but dynamically, i.e. *calculated for each month how many accounts exists which also had transactions within both previous months?*

```
SELECT trans_month, Count(*)
FROM
 (
   SELECT
      ACCT_NBR,
     ,Trunc(TRAN_DT, 'mon') AS trans_month -- 1st of month
   FROM TRAN
   WHERE
      TRAN.TRAN_CD IN ('id1','id2','id3')  --Filters on Transaction IDs
--    AND
--      TRAN.TRAN_DT BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'
   GROUP BY ACCT_NBR, trans_month -- distinct list first
   QUALIFY 
      -- check if there are three consecutive months
      -- e.g. 
      -- 2017-02-01 <- 2 preceding, must be 2 months before current row
      -- 2017-03-01 <- 1 preceding
      -- 2017-04-01 <- current row
      Min(trans_month)
      Over (PARTITION BY ACCT_NBR
            ORDER BY trans_month
            ROWS 2 Preceding) = Add_Months(trans_month,-2)
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY trans_month
ORDER BY trans_month
```

Comment: That did the trick.  I'll just figure out a way for it to also show calendar results in the data pull.  Thanks!

Comment: @starfly: What calendar results, `DATE '2017-01-01'`? You got a hard-coded date range and you want to count customers with rows in each month

Comment: I want to have a date column in the format YYYYMM (which is why I joined CLDR) and then get to a point where for any given month, it pulls the last 3 months for TRAN_DT.  So if CLDR month is 201703, pull TRAN_DT 2017-01-01 - 2017-03-31; if CLDR month is 201702, pull TRAN_DT 2016-12-01 - 2017-02-28.  Is there a straightforward way to do so?

Comment: @starfly:  Your example was based on a known range of three months, if you want to do this calculation dynamically the approach will be totally different.

Comment: thanks for adding the edit.  Very helpful and educational, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

A brute force approach would be to add an `IN` clause for each month:

```
AND TRAN.ACCT_NBR IN (
       SELECT ACCT_NBR 
       FROM REPORTS.FINANCIAL_TRAN 
       WHERE TRAN_DT BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31')
AND TRAN.ACCT_NBR IN (
       SELECT ACCT_NBR 
       FROM REPORTS.FINANCIAL_TRAN 
       WHERE TRAN_DT BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-02-28')
AND TRAN.ACCT_NBR IN (
       SELECT ACCT_NBR 
       FROM REPORTS.FINANCIAL_TRAN 
       WHERE TRAN_DT BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-03-31')
```

Comment: And this would become part of the WHERE clause, correct?  I'll try this to see if it gets me the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it in MSSQL. I'm pretty sure you have the windowing functions in Teradata.

I'm simplifying your data for my test example but this should get you on the right track. The reason for the CTE is you can't use COUNT DISTINCT in window function.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (
     ACCT_NBR int
    ,YEAR_MONTH char(5)
    ,TRAN_DT datetime )

INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 123, '17/01', '2017-01-11';
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 123, '17/02', '2017-02-12';
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 123, '17/02', '2017-02-21';
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 123, '17/03', '2017-03-19';
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 356, '17/01', '2017-01-14';
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 356, '17/01', '2017-01-22';
INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT 356, '17/03', '2017-03-14';

SELECT * FROM #Test;

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
         ACCT_NBR AS AccountNumber
        ,YEAR_MONTH AS YYMM
    FROM #Test
    WHERE TRAN_DT BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31' )

SELECT DISTINCT
     YYMM
    ,COUNT(AccountNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY YYMM ) AS Counts
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thanks.  I unfortunately don't have write access to the DBMS, so can't create (temporary) tables.

Comment: Use table variables then. Or ask for permission. Or just access the fact that user7593937 just show you an example and you can use your table.

Comment: The temp table was just to give me some data to work with, to try and replicate the data you were working with--the solution doesn't require a temp table. Just use your query in the CTE and then use the window function to do your counts.